# Selecting every n indices of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array that is 100 elements in length, what is the most Pythonic way to get every n indices.  For example, if I wanted every 5 indices of an array `a`, how could I get an array `b=[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],...]`, where each element of `b` is a sub-array of every 5 indices?

Comment: `a.reshape(-1,5)` or `np.reshape(a, (-1, 5))`

Comment: No, `list` doesn't have a shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

If you are using lists, a very pythonic way to do it:

```
size = 5 # the number of elements of each sublists
l = list(range(100))
result = [l[step:step + size] for step in range(0, len(l), size)]
```

**Ouput:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54], [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
 [60, 61, 62, 63, 64], [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
 [70, 71, 72, 73, 74], [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
 [80, 81, 82, 83, 84], [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94], [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Comment: I think the OP is working with `numpy` arrays, regardless, `[e for e in l[step:step + n]]` is a bit redundant. All you need is `[l[step:step + n] for n in range(0, len(l), size)]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I try running your line, and I am getting an error

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are running, but if `x` is your list, then `[x[n:5 + n] for n in range(0, len(x),5)]` should work

Comment: Think about it, `[e for e in some_list]` is *just `some_list`* and since your `some_list` is already a slice, it's already a copy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I ran `[l[step:step + n] for n in range(0, len(l), size)]`, but the code aboves works, and I have updated my answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks once again for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

You simply want to `reshape` your array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(100)
>>> arr
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
>>> arr.reshape(-1, 5)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
       [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Note, I used `-1` on the first axis, `numpy` is smart enough to "solve the equation" as long as you give it every other axis explicitly. You could have, of course, done this completely explicitly:

```
>>> arr.reshape(20, 5)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
       [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Comment: what if I wanted to get every n = odd index from an even length array.  For example if I wanted every 3 indices in an array of length 100?

Comment: @maelstromscientist using slicing: `arr[::3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = range(100)
>>> step = 5
>>> [L[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(L), step)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
 [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
 [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
 [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
 [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
 [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
 [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
 [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
 [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
 [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
 [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
 [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Seems a natural way to do it to me.